# Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have been looking for some security scenarios for web security. I have searched for various attacks, how they can be exploited and prevented, but just theoretically. I tried finding out how Spring security can prevent different attacks like DOS, SQL Injection, CRLF, CSHM, CSRF, Directory Traversal etc. but didn't find any specific document for it. Can anyone give me an example of each or some document to refer?

Comment: Reference - http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look to HDIV project, it integrates very well with spring framework.
It provides a very easy and clean xml configuration.
It's also updated for OWASP top 10 vulnerabilities

Answer (score 1):

Create Domain class for UserDetails

```js
package com.apmc.domain;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
 
@Entity
public class UserDetails {
     
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long u_id;
     
    private String u_login;
     
    private String u_password;
     
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="u_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="r_id")}
    )
    private Set<Role> u_roles;
    
    
    //**************************************Setter and Getter *************
                              
}
```

Create Role Domain class

```js
package com.apmc.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Role {
     
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer r_id;
     
    private String r_role;
     
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles", 
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="r_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="u_id")}
    )
    private UserDetails r_user;
    
    //***************************************Getter And Setter *************************
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
  
<http auto-config="false">  
      
    <intercept-url access="ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN" pattern="/Admin/Super_admin/*" /> 
    <intercept-url access="ROLE_ADMIN" pattern="/Admin/admin/*" />  
    <intercept-url access="ROLE_USER_EVP" pattern="/Entry/entryVehiclePass/*" />  
    <intercept-url access="ROLE_USER_EGP" pattern="/Entry/entryGatePass/*" />  
    <intercept-url access="ROLE_USER_AUC, ROLE_USER_WTR" pattern="/Auction/*" />  
    <intercept-url access="ROLE_USER_TOLMAP" pattern="/Tolmap/*" /> 
    <intercept-url access="ROLE_USER_EXTGP" pattern="/Exit/exitGatePass/*" />   
          
      <form-login authentication-failure-url="/error-login" default-target-url="/success-login" login-page="/user-login" />  
      <logout logout-success-url="/" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />  
        
    <headers>
  <cache-control />
  <hsts max-age-seconds="0" />
 </headers>
   
</http>  

     <authentication-manager>  
         <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">  
             <password-encoder hash="plaintext">  
             </password-encoder>  
         </authentication-provider>  
        </authentication-manager>
        
</beans:beans>
```

Above code for spring-security.xml

```js
package com.apmc.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class SecurityNavigation {
     
    @RequestMapping(value="/user-login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loginForm() {
        return new ModelAndView("login-form");
    }
     
    @RequestMapping(value="/error-login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView invalidLogin() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("login-form");
        modelAndView.addObject("error", true);
        return modelAndView;
    }
     
    @RequestMapping(value="/success-login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView successLogin() {
        return new ModelAndView("success-login");
    }
    
}
```

Above code for Security Controller

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  
<html>
<head>

<style>
.error {
 padding: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 4px;
 color: #a94442;
 background-color: #f2dede;
 border-color: #ebccd1;
}

.msg {
 padding: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 4px;
 color: #31708f;
 background-color: #d9edf7;
 border-color: #bce8f1;
}

#login-box {
 width: 300px;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 100px auto;
 background: #fff;
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>

 <h1>Spring Security Custom Login Form (XML)</h1>

 <div id="login-box">

  <h2>Login with Username and Password</h2>

  <c:if test="${error == true}">
   <div class="error">
    Invalid login or password.
   </div>
  </c:if>
  
  <form name='loginForm'
    action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>

    <table>
   <tr>
    <td>User:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name="j_username" id="j_username" ></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type='password' name="j_password" id="j_password" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
     value="submit" /></td>
   </tr>
    </table>

  </form>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

login-form.jsp write as above way

```html
<div align="right"> <a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />" >Logout</a> </div>
```

write this code in All jsp file logout.jsp include

Answer (score 1):

For Different role you can use like this. Let's use basic type of it.

```
    <http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/manager**" access="ROLE_MANAGER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/employee**" access="ROLE_EMPLOYEE" />
</http>
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
    <user name="Manager" password="400" authorities="ROLE_MANAGER" />
    <user name="employee" password="000" authorities="ROLE_EMPLOYEE" />
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```